# Calling Thread.Sleep in Subscriber thread causes Publisher thread to sleep

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns

I have implemented Publish and Subscribe pattern in my application but when I called `Thread.sleep()` method in any one Subscriber or any one of my Subscriber throws exception then all others subscribers and publishers gets affected by this so how can I prevent this from happening.

I have created one small demo of above problem

Publisher Code

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Publisher extends Thread {

    Broker broker = Broker.getInstance();
    Random random = new Random();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Published " + new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            broker.updateSubscribers(Integer.toString(random.nextInt(250)));
        }

    }
}
```

Subscriber Interface

```
public interface Subscriber {

    public void onUpdate(String message);
}
```

MessageSubscriber code

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class MessageSubscriber extends Thread implements Subscriber {

    Broker broker = Broker.getInstance();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("MessageSubscriber started...");
        broker.subscribe(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(String message) {
        try {
            System.out.println(message);
            sleep(1000);                    // called sleep affects the publisher too
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MessageSubscriber.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see I have called sleep method in MessageSubscriber which also affects the Publisher and makes it sleep too for that duration

Edit added Broker Code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author hemants
 */
public class Broker {

    List<Subscriber> subscribersList = new ArrayList<>();

    private Broker() {
    }

    public static Broker getInstance() {
        return BrokerHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    private static class BrokerHolder {

        private static final Broker INSTANCE = new Broker();
    }

    public void subscribe(Subscriber s) {
        subscribersList.add(s);
    }

    public void unsubscribe(Subscriber s) {
        subscribersList.remove(s);
    }

    public void updateSubscribers(String message) {
        subscribersList.stream().forEach(subscriber -> subscriber.onUpdate(message));
    }
}
```

Main class to run above code

```
public class PubSubPattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Publisher publisher = new Publisher();
        publisher.start();

        MessageSubscriber messageSubscriber = new MessageSubscriber();
        messageSubscriber.start();
    }
}
```

Well I have edited my MessageSubscribe code like below and it is doing kind of what I have expected

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author hemants
 */
public class MessageSubscriber extends Thread implements Subscriber {

    Broker broker = Broker.getInstance();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("MessageSubscriber started...");

        while (true) {
            try {
                broker.subscribe(this);
                System.out.println("subscribed ");
                sleep(1000);
                broker.unsubscribe(this);
                System.out.println("un subscribed");
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MessageSubscriber.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

}
```

What do you say about this

Comment: Where does the `Broker` come from?

Comment: @LuCio please check I have added the broker code

Comment: This makes it obvious. See the answers.

Comment: @LuCio please see the edit

Comment: *Calling Thread.Sleep in Subscriber thread causes Publisher thread to sleep* this statement is wrong - Sleep is called in Publisher's thread thus it sleeps. Sleep is placed **in subscriber code** - that is true.

Answer (score 1):

So you execute sometyhing like this

```
subscribersList.stream().forEach(subscriber -> subscriber.onUpdate(message));
```

and during `onUpdate` you `sleep`

so its effectively

```
subscribersList.stream().forEach(subscriber -> Thread.sleep());
```

or even more verbose

```
for(Subscriber sub:subscribers){
   Thread.sleep(xxx);
}
```

No wonder it "affects" other listener as caller is blocked here. Caller thread sleeps on every element.

Either use thread pool and submit update tasks, or use `subscribersList.parallelStream()`

I hope this is only for educational purposes.

Comment: Where should I use `ThreadPool` in `Broker` class can you show me how to

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html - you will find dozens of how-tos using google.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the subscriber in same thread that is why it will affect the other subscriber. And also block the Publisher.

Create new Thread to update the broker and it would be fine.

Comment: Yes I got that but I cannot do that because in my application publishing rate is high say like 100 records per minute then according this it will create 100 threads to update the broker perminute

Comment: Then you can use thread pool and specify the maximum number of thread that your machine can handle.

Comment: Or you can also use the parallelStream() in broker.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution. I updated the `MessageSubscriber` to keep the usage of the interface `Subscriber` within the `Broker`:

```
public class MessageSubscriber extends Thread implements Subscriber {

    Broker broker = Broker.getInstance();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("MessageSubscriber started...");
        synchronized (broker) {
            broker.subscribe(this);
        }
        try {
            synchronized (this) {
                wait();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            // TODO OP has to decide how to handle this
            // for example
            synchronized (broker) {
                broker.unsubscribe(this);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(String message) {
        try {
            synchronized (this) {
                notify();
            }
            System.out.println(message);
            sleep(1000); // called sleep affects the publisher too
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            Logger.getLogger(MessageSubscriber.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

I'm not sure about the handling of the `InterruptedException` within `run()` as the lock for `boker` has to be aquired to enter the synchronized block. Thus it's possible that the thread will wait for this lock instead of interrupting itself effectively.